# npm install from within a docker fails when ran in synology dsm but works locally

Tags: node.js, docker, npm

Well in a try to automate building a bit more the build is moved to a docker - however while this works in our local setup it doesn't in the remote server.

The dockerfile for the build process looks like;

```
FROM node:14-alpine
RUN apk update
RUN apk upgrade
RUN apk add rsync
RUN apk add git less openssh

RUN mkdir /javascript
WORKDIR /javascript

RUN npm install flow-remove-types -g

ENTRYPOINT npm ci
```

And after building it is called through:

```
sudo docker run -it --volume=/home/paul/project/javascript:/javascript \
    --volume=/home/paul/.ssh:/home/node/.ssh \
    --volume=/home/paul/.ssh:/root/.ssh \
    --volume=/home/paul/.npm:/home/node/.npm \
    --entrypoint "sh" buildimagedocker
```

(Entrypoint is changed for testing purposes).

If I then start and type "npm install" or "npm ci" I get the following error:

```
npm ERR! Error while executing:
npm ERR! /usr/bin/git ls-remote -h -t ssh://git@<GITSERVER>
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! No user exists for uid 1028
npm ERR! fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please make sure you have the correct access rights
npm ERR! and the repository exists.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! exited with error code: 128

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-09-25T15_18_53_397Z-debug.log
```

However manually cloning from the git works just fine - so it must be a problem with the npm installation.

Furthermore the same docker works just fine at my local pc, only in the synology dsm it gives a problem.

I've seen the same problem report [here](https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/624). However there it was denoted as "fixed" already. I tested the current npm version:

npm --version: 6.14.8

So what goes wrong, and how do I work around this?

EDIT, the big difference is that in my local pc the files permissions look like:

```
drwxr-xr-x    2 node     node          4096 Sep 25 13:45 bin
drwxr-xr-x   10 node     node          4096 Sep 25 13:45 build
drwxr-xr-x    2 node     node          4096 Sep 25 13:45 config
```

while on remote it looks like:

```
drwxr-xr-x    2 1028     users         4096 Sep 25 15:18 bin
drwxr-xr-x    2 1028     users         4096 Sep 25 15:18 build
drwxr-xr-x    2 1028     users         4096 Sep 25 15:18 config
```

Outside the docker the same files look like (local):

```
drwxr-xr-x  2 paul paul   4096 sep 25 15:45 bin
drwxr-xr-x 10 paul paul   4096 sep 25 15:45 build
drwxr-xr-x  2 paul paul   4096 sep 25 15:45 config
```

remote:

```
drwxrwxrwx+   2 PaulWeijtens users   4096 Sep 25 17:18 bin
drwxrwxrwx+   2 PaulWeijtens users   4096 Sep 25 17:18 build
drwxrwxrwx+   2 PaulWeijtens users   4096 Sep 25 17:18 config
```

Comment: @Which OS you are using?

Comment: @RichardRublev on my local install ubuntu, while remote is synology dsm. But the idea of docker is to not have to worry about the host os?

Comment: I agree,isolation is the point.

Comment: This is a permissions error on your mounted volumes. They are set to user id `1028` locally but this user ID does not exist in the container.

Comment: Well one other thing to note is that this only happens when there is a git package inside the repository.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was indeed a permissions problem but wasn't solved as explained by the answer of doublesharp. I fixed it by refactoring how the files work. In this answer I'll try to explain how and why I did the things (for future denvercoder9s). I might not be exactly correct and please correct me in comments, or update the answer (I am just starting to "get" this).

The files under `/home/node/.ssh` and `/root/.ssh` were not owned by the current user running. Normally this isn't a problem as the programs are read as "root" from inside docker.

And while the main process is indeed run as root in the `alpine:node` docker, anything run by `npm` seems to deescalate permissions to a `node` user. For this reason running the docker as user `1028` didn't work, the files were still being accessed as if it was user `node`.

The solution hence was to change the file permissions, but since doing that in a volume would also change the permission on the host, I opted to instead refactor the docker and *copy* the files into the docker using the `Dockerfile`.

```
COPY local/ssh/ /root/.ssh/
COPY local/ssh/ /home/node/.ssh/
```

This however meant the file had `777` as permission mask, and ssh complained (quite violently) that it would not accept a file readable by others. Running `chmod` to hange the mask to 400 however gave the problem with permissions again, since `npm` is not ran as `root` or the same user creating the docker the files couldn't be accessed during running. So the directory ownership had to be changed to the user `node`.

Finally since on remote the home directory is in a different location than on my local pc I opted to not use home for the ssh location. Instead using a local ssh directory.

The resulting dockerfile looks now like:

```
FROM node:14-alpine
RUN apk update
RUN apk upgrade

RUN mkdir /javascript
WORKDIR /javascript


RUN npm install flow-remove-types -g

COPY --chown=node:node local/ssh/ /root/.ssh/
COPY --chown=node:node local/ssh/ /home/node/.ssh/
RUN chmod 400 /root/.ssh/id_rsa
RUN chmod 400 /home/node/.ssh/id_rsa

ENTRYPOINT chown -R node:node . && npm ci
```

And the call like

```
sudo docker run -it --volume=/home/paul/project/javascript:/javascript \
    --volume=/home/paul/.npm:/home/node/.npm \
    --entrypoint "sh" buildimagedocker
```

Important bit to notice is that the `alpine:node` dockers will run the `npm` process not as use `node`, not `root`. And changing the user id for a docker has no effect on this.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to install to a mounted volume that has permissions set on the host to user ID `1028` but does not exist in the container so you can't write to the volume. To fix you can either set permissions on the volume to be more open, create a user with the same ID inside the container, or start the containers with the `-u` argument to specify the UID.

See the last line for specifying the UID and this article for more info on [GID/UID with docker](https://medium.com/@mccode/understanding-how-uid-and-gid-work-in-docker-containers-c37a01d01cf) and this section of the [Docker documentation for USER](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#user).

sudo d

```
ocker run -it --volume=/home/paul/project/javascript:/javascript \
    --volume=/home/paul/.ssh:/home/node/.ssh \
    --volume=/home/paul/.ssh:/root/.ssh \
    --volume=/home/paul/.npm:/home/node/.npm \
    --entrypoint "sh" buildimagedocker \
    -u 1028:1028
```

It's also not generally recommended to share the `node_modules` and related files with the container as they will not work if the host and container are different operating systems, versions of node, etc.

Comment: Hmm but how would I share the "current user" this way? Without hard typing the id? -- Also why would it then work on my local pc, where the owner is "paul", and in the node container you can see the user "paul" isn't existing and ownership is changed to "node"

Comment: It's going to be problematic to rely on the current user and better to design a different setup, but if you want to use the current UID you can do this: `-u $(id -u):$(id -g)`

Comment: Well the files are supplied by another docker (which is purely git to download it) this docker would build the files and then pass it onward to a test docker. -- I still can't wrap my head around why it would work locally but not remote. Why does the local docker "map" the user permissions while the remote doesn't?

Comment: Also this does *not* fix the problem, exactly the same error pops up after I supply it to the correct user id (1028) and group id (100).